# When creating a post how do you select the format?

Tags: posts, wp-insert-post

When creating a post [programmatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/151741/how-to-programmatically-create-posts-in-wordpress) (with `wp_insert_post();`), how do you select the format?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you mean by "format"? The `post_type`?

Comment: If enabled by themes, WordPress supports post formats: image, aside, quote, video, etc..

Comment: I've never worked with post formats before, but this may point you in the right direction: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_format/. If nothing else, you should be able to create a post, and then use `set_post_format()` after that. Probably not the most efficient way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As post_format is a custom taxonomy and the different formats terms, you should be able to use the `tax_input` parameter in the new post args array to set the format. Something along these lines,

```
$new_post_args = array();

// e.g. $format_slug = 'gallery';
$valid_formats = get_post_format_slugs();
if ( 'standard' !== $format_slug && in_array( $format_slug, $valid_formats ) ) {
  $new_post_args['tax_input']['post_format'] = 'post-format-' . $format_slug;
}

wp_insert_post( $new_post_args );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$post_id  = wp_insert_post( $args );
$tag = 'post-format-test';
$taxonomy = 'post_format';
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: That's certainly an interesting hack. It doesn't entirely surprise me that formats are stored as an internal taxonomy. I think I'll stick with `set_post_format()` as suggested in comments.